# How do I restore a plain text postgres .backup file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I exported a postgres db from pgAdmin in a plain format because I wanted to search the whole db text. I then tried to restore the database back but it gives an error saying that the archive file is not valid archive file. How do I restore the db back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the PLAIN format is SQL. To Quote the [documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/backup.html):

> pg_dump does not support all options for all backup file formats.
>   Particularly, to backup blobs the PLAIN format can not be used. Also,
>   a PLAIN file can not be interpreted, and can not be restored using
>   pgAdmin. The PLAIN format will create an SQL script that can be
>   executed using the psql tool. For standard backup and restore
>   purposes, the COMPRESS and TAR options are recommended.

I'm assuming you could restore using something like (on unix):

```
psql < backup-file
```

or from inside psql prompt (newdb is an empty db)

```
psql newdb
newdb=# \i backup-file
```

You might have to run as privileged user '`postgres`' (on unix, say) or pass the appropriate credentials for the role to `psql` so that it can create the db and roles and other entities indicated by the backup-file. The create database and role statements might not be present in the backup depending on whether it has the *entire server* (it has) or just one database (you should create the db and role(s)). So you'd have to create them before restoring it.

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: You should still be able to do it using the psql.exe bundled with pgadmin. The default installation should put it some where like `C:\Program Files\pgAdmin III\1.14>`

Comment: Just tried it myself and would like to point out two nuances with the `psql.exe` on windows. You might have to set the environment variable `PGCLIENTENCODING` to the encoding your (empty) db is created with. Also, I had to specify the backup file path using '/' (forward slashes), i.e. `db-# \i C:/Temp/db.backup`